# How to calculate the variance of stocks of the last 36 months (some monthly data are missing)?

Tags: python

I downloaded some stock data from CRSP and need the variance of the stock returns of the last 36 months of that company.

So, basically the variance based on two conditions:

- Same PERMCO (company number)
- Monthly stock returns of the last 3 years.

However, I excluded penny stocks from my sample (stocks with prices < $2). Hence, sometimes months are missing and e.g. april and junes monthly returns are directly on top of each other.

If I am not mistaken, a rolling function (grouped by Permco) would just take the 36 monthly returns above. But when months are missing, the rolling function would actually take more than 3 years data (since the last 36 monthly returns would exceed that timeframe).

Usually I work with Ms Excel. However, in this case the amount of data is too big and it takes years to let Excel calculate stuff. Thats why I want to tackle that problem with Python.
The sample is organized as follows:

```
PERMNO date SHRCD PERMCO PRC RET
```

When I have figured out how to make a proper table in here I will show you a sample of my data.

What I have tried so far:

```
data["RET"]=data["RET"].replace(["C","B"], np.nan)
data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(date["date"])
data=data.sort_values[("PERMCO" , "date"]).reset_index()
L3Yvariance=data.groupby("PERMCO")["RET"].rolling(36).var().reset_index()
```

Sometimes there are C and B instead of actual returns, thats why the first line

Comment: add some code of what you tried, because if you don't it does not meet the Stackoverflow Guidelines ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the missing values by the mean value. It won't affect the variance as the variance is calculated after subtracting the mean, so in this case, for times you won't have the value, the contribution to variance will be 0.

Comment: Since the mean would change depending on what 36 returns are taken into consideration, I think its best to simply ignore them. Dont you think so?